# Get the id of input on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input box...

```
<input type="text" id="search_member" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);">
```

When I type in the field, it will go to function lookup(). From there I want to get the id of this input. I tried...

```
var This_id = $(this).attr("id");
```

but this won't work. Any suggestions on how I can get the id?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you are passing `this.value` to your `lookup()` function. It's better to pass `this` to your function and then use `arg.value` to get the value and `arg.getAttribute('id')` for the `id`

```
<input type="text" id="search_member" onkeyup="lookup(this);">

function lookup(arg){
 var id = arg.getAttribute('id');
 var value = arg.value;
 // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of `onkeyup="lookup(this.value);`

```
<input type="text" id="search_member">
```

and then use

```
$(function(){
    $("#search_member").keyup(function(e){
        var This_id = $(this).attr("id");
    });
};
```

Comment: @Joe, since you are already using jQuery, you should avoid having event handlers in the HTML. This is the preferred way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.activeElement != undefined) {
     var id = $(e.currentTarget.activeElement).attr('id');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is you're not passing the element in, you're passing the value. You need to change it to this:

```
<input type="text" id="search_member" onkeyup="lookup(this);">
```

Then the rest of your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you give the function lookup the THIS?

```
 lookup(this);
```

then u can also use the code you suggested

Answer (score 0):

To get the `id` you should use `this.id` not `this.value`. I hope it work with you